# I don't know how to save the localStorage when I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, page-refresh

I explain my problem: I am doing a question game by rounds with react and JS, when you get a round right, the page refreshes and depending on the number of rounds you have, it takes you to another question of greater difficulty.

The problem comes here: In the Home.JS file I have declared the LocalStorage, so that it is always 0 (When you fail the question takes you to Home and the rounds are reset to 0):

```
localStorage.setItem("numRounds", 0)
```

In the Question.JS file, when I hit the question, enter the validateQuestion method, here I receive the home localstorage which is 0, then I create a variable where I save the localstorage data and add a counter for each question that is correct is +1 (Raises the level of difficulty of the question) and then I save it in the localStorage, adding the variable that I have created (Using console.log, we can check that it goes perfectly):

```
validateQuestion(e){
        var answerUser = e.currentTarget.innerHTML;
        var answercorrect = this.state.question.Answer_Correct //(This is api does not matter to the 
        problem)
        if (answercorrect == answerUser){
            alert("CORRECT")
            var numRounds = localStorage.getItem("numRounds");
            console.log(numRounds);
            numRounds++
            localStorage.setItem("numRounds", numRounds);
            console.log(localStorage.getItem("numRounds"));
            window.location.assign("http://localhost:3000/question");
        }
        else{
            alert("FAIL")
            window.location.assign("http://localhost:3000/");
        }
    }
```

But when I refresh the page, the localStorage returns to number 0 and it will not be saved correctly, so that I advance the questions to greater difficulty (That is through another method) .. Any solution to this?

Greetings and thanks!

Comment: it might be a string/number thing. Try this edit: `var numRounds = Number(localStorage.getItem("numRounds"));`

Comment: did you write this line at the `componentdidmount` or `useEffect ` `localStorage.setItem("numRounds", 0)` if you did write. It will reset when ever page reload

Comment: I have made a "componentWillMount ()" (I don't know if it will be the same or not) but the line is out, this more than nothing I have it for the API call and select the question

Answer (score 0):

The localStorage can only store strings for each key.
It needs to be converted back into a number when you read it so it can be added correctly.

```
var numRounds = Number(localStorage.getItem("numRounds"));
numRounds ++;
```

Comment: I have done it as is and nothing, the localStorage will be saved, but when I refresh the page (With window.location.assign ("http: //localhost:300/question")) to get another question it stays again at 0.